# Parse and get full text result with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm fully newbies and i start with BeautifulSoup and Python and i want to get a result in full text without any HTML tags or other elements that are not text.

For information, i work with HTML5 document.

I did this :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_content = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.demo.com/index.html")

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")

# Synthax for Beautiful Soup 4.1.2 - NO WORK
# title = soup.find_all("h2", class_="boc2")

# Synthax for Beautiful Soup VS ??? - WORK FINE
# title = soup.find_all("h2", "boc1")

big_title = [h1.string for h1 in soup.find_all("h1", "headline")]
title = [h2.string for h2 in soup.find_all("h2", "boc1")]
aside_title = [h2.string for h2 in soup.find_all("h2", "boc2")]

print big_title, title, aside_title

raw_input()
```

and I get this:

```
[u'title in header headline'] [u'title in section boc1'] [u'title in aside boc2']
```

I would get this:

```
title in header headline
title in section boc1
title in aside boc2
```

Comment: Is there any difference between you actual output and expected output?

Comment: Yes, in expected output, i don't have [u' and '] !

Just TEXT, only TEXT

Comment: it's unicode string. if you dont want the leading `u''` then try this, `big_title = [str(h1.string) for h1 in soup.find_all("h1", "headline")]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK..I got you.

Try this:

```
...
print big_title[0], title[0], aside_title[0]

raw_input()
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are getting is unicode strings. Though when scraping, unicode is much better choice, but if you want to get rid of the `u` prefix, do this,

```
big_title = [str(h1.string) for h1 in soup.find_all("h1", "headline")]
title = [str(h2.string) for h2 in soup.find_all("h2", "boc1")]
aside_title = [str(h2.string) for h2 in soup.find_all("h2", "boc2")]
```

For printing the text only, print the `0th` element of the lists (as you have only one element in each list). Like,

```
print big_title[0]
```